# Short white flash before the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an inconsistent problem with my website. Between page loads, sometimes there is a white flash before the page completely loads. It is only for an instant, and it happens about 85% of the time. Furthermore, **it only happens in Chrome**.

I have tried putting script before the ending body tag and it has helped the other browsers, but not Chrome.

Can someone please show me what is wrong?

Could it have anything to do with conflicting CSS? Is there any way to pre-load the page before displaying it without doing an `onload` event that sets the visibility of the html to visible, as that does not solve the problem; the page is still white.

**EDIT 1:**

You may notice sometimes that the background image loads slow, so the background is a dark blue for a split second. That is not what I am referring to. It appears to be a special case situation. Sometimes it does that for me, sometimes it is **completely** white for just a brief moment before the page appears.

Comment: Tested on Chrome 24 on Mac.  I wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: Any similar cases? I'm running 24.0 on Mountain Lion as well as Canary 26.0 and it happens on both for me.

Comment: Are you talking about the thing that happens when the background with the gradient loads? I couldn't see anything alarming either. (Windows here) :[

Comment: Yes, in some cases, the background doesn't appear until after the page loads, and in some cases, the page is just completely white for a split second.

Comment: windows 7, chrome 23, can't see any problem except what Sanchit is talking about

Comment: I don't get it. This seems like the way that all web pages ordinarily load and not a real problem.

Comment: Its cause you have THREE backgrounds for your page. In class `page`, `page-body-img`, and `page-body-b` I guess its causing some inconsistency. Perhaps add in the blue color `background: #5685E4 url(filename) otherstuff;` to all those classes?

Comment: Every site I opened within the past few minutes is completely white until the page appears. It's normal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the browser is simply parsing the CSS of the body background (white) before your bg images have time to load. Unfortunately, I don't have any quick fixes for this. You could get rid of the background image gradient and use CSS, this might stop the flashing.